# Lock Horizontal View

Tags: android

I want to lock horizontal view in my app, is it possible?

Help is highly appreciated,

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this code in your menifest...

```
<activity android:name=".activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"   android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

Comment: this is vertical orientation.

Answer (score 7):

Use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` attribute for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

For new android Studio 3 and above
you need to put these lines in **AndroidManifest.xml** code if you want to set the orientation to portrait

One thing this is sensor portrait, means both upside - downside will work.

But if you only want to put portrait for upside then, **replace sensorPortrait to portrait**

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
```

Same goes for only landscape too
just one parameter change portrait to landscape

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation= "sensorLandscape"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
```