# Android, landscape only orientation?

Tags: android

How can I make it so the screen orientation is always landscape?

Do I need to add something to the `manifest.xml`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock Horizontal View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814960/lock-horizontal-view)

Answer (score 104):

Add this `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to your `<activity>` tag in the manifest for the specific activity that you want to be in landscape.

**Edit:**

To toggle the orientation from the `Activity` code, call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` other parameters can be found in the Android docs for [ActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html).

Comment: Any way to make this setting application-level?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I assume you mean from the code in your `Activity`? If so, I updated my answer to reflect that with an example.

Comment: Hi, I meant from the <application> level tag in the Manifest.  Like when you specify device compatibility requirements, I was wondering if there was a way to specify landscape-only there as well.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Ohhh gotcha, yeah I do not believe so. This must be specified on a per `Activity` basis at the moment. They could possibly  add this as an option in the `android:uiOptions` attribute but I doubt it.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, in `AndroidManifest.xml`, declare your `Activity` like so: `<activity ... android:screenOrientation="landscape" .../>`

Answer (score 11):

Just two steps needed:

1. Apply `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` after setContentView().
2. In the AndroidMainfest.xml, put this statement `<activity android:name=".YOURCLASSNAME" android:screenOrientation="landscape"  />`

Hope it helps and happy coding :)

Comment: *Note*: `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` and `landscape` switch off the sensor, so it is only *one* of the possible two landscape configurations – there are `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE` and `reverseLandscape` as well. If you just want to have a landscape app without forcing the user to hold the device in one of the two ways, use `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE` and `sensorLandscape`. [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation)

Comment: @Bowi Thanks for the SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE!!! Saved my life (and my monitor's life)! I was really annoyed that I couldn't make it flit only between landscape orientations!

Answer (score 9):

One thing I've not found through the answers is that there are ***two*** possible landscape orientations, and I wanted to let both be available!
So `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` will lock your app only to one of the 2 possibilities, but if you want your app to be limited to *both* landscape orientations (for them whom is not clear, having device on portrait, one is rotating left and the other one rotating right) this is what is needed:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

Comment: More values https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen

Answer (score 4):

When you are in android studio 3 or above
you need to add following lines **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation= "sensorLandscape"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
```

One thing this is sensor Landscape, means it will work on both landscape sides

But if you only want to work the regular landscape side then, **replace sensorLandscape to landscape**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: OP is asking how to set to landscape, not portrait.