# Android:Landscape mode throughout the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

How can I possible set landscape mode throughout my application ? I can add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

in my all activities. But then its very redundant code and it possible be error prone as the application evolves. Can't I set landscape mode for my whole application in one place only ?

Comment: How that one line of code is prone to errors? Just curious to know.

Comment: I might miss some activity in which this might be not set !! You have to very careful that each time you write an activity this orientation attribute has to be set

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9784269/1891118

Comment: @ shomeser I think you didn't read the question properly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can do this both programmatically and for all your activities making an AbstractActivity that all your activities extends.

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

This abstract activity can also be used for a global menu.

Comment: Edited my answer !! Although my answer is almost the same as yours

Comment: When you copy the answer please mention the source from where you copied. Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only

Answer (score 1):

Make an AbstractActivity that all your activities extends.
This will set the orientation programmaticaly for all of them.

```
public abstract class LandscapeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. Adding it to the `application` element does nothing. You have no alternative to adding it to each activity.

Comment: Are you sure ? Though I also could not find something which could be set once.

Comment: Ha! Nothing is certain with Android development. But yeah, I'm sure. There's no known way to accomplish a full application setting of orientation via the manifest. At least not at the time of writing this and up though version 19. There *are* ways of doing it via extending a custom abstract Activity base class or by subclassing the Application class, but those don't seem worth the effort unless you need them for another reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

also see [Android, landscape only orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408197/android-landscape-only-orientation)